# Git status showing many deleted files after running git pull

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

There are a few people (including me) who are working on one project. I haven’t been spending much time on it over the last while and so had not committed in a few weeks.

Having updated my local repo with my new changes, running git status showed loads of new and modified files, these being ones others had changed or created.

I assumed this is because git was thinking the most recent version was the one I had committed weeks beforehand so I decided it was safer to update my local repo first and then start again.

I thus ran git pull to update my local repo. It then said it could not do this as many files were duplicates (or something along these lines) so I deleted the files in my local repo manually and ran git pull again. Having done this I checked git status and it is now showing me many deleted files which should be there.

These files exist on gitlab but for some reason were not pulled to my local repo.

Could anyone help me as to what might have caused this or a different method to try?

Answer (score 0):

As you have manually deleted some "duplicate" files, git thinks they are changes when you run `git status`. You do not want these changes.

So, run `git reset --hard hash_of_your_commited_new_changes` to go back to your previous commit, i.e. you mentioned you have "updated" your local repo.

You may run `git log --oneline --decorate` to identify *hash_of_your_commited_new_changes*.

Finally, run `git pull -r` to pull the latest changes from others and rebased your last commit on top of theirs.